# How to detect CPU time of an application in IOS

Tags: ios, iphone, ios9, cpu, cpu-usage

I know that there are some apps (like [system panel lite](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=nextapp.systempanel)) for Android that are able to detect/measure the CPU time of a certain application (per PID or UID).
My concern is if this is possible to do in iOS. If yes, then is there any API able to measure CPU time of individual applications?

The reason I am asking is because I want my app to be able to detect and measure the CPU time of certain apps and do something with this info.

Comment: Instruments.app (comes with Xcode) lets you do various profiling on iOS apps. You might want to be more specific in your question for a more specific answer.

Comment: Are you looking to measure the CPU usage of your app or are you trying to write an app of your own to measure the CPU usage of other apps?

Comment: I am sorry for not being specific in my question! I am developing an app and what i want to do is to measure the cpu time of other apps and do something with this info.

Answer (score 0):

Check [System status lite](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/system-status-lite-cpu-battery-storage-monitor/id407752428?mt=8) if you are looking for app.

Better way is using Xcode, please see [Measure CPU Use](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/MeasuringCPUUse.html) apple developer page.